# I am trying to install ros-noetic- to my device

Tags: ubuntu, ros

I set the following command to terminal:

```
sudo apt install ros-noetic-
```

And it gives the following error:

`E: Unable to locate package ros-noetic`

How can I fix it ?!

note: I have already installed ROS according to the instructions at http://wiki.ros.org/noetic/Installation/Ubuntu on ubuntu 20.04

Comment: which package are you trying to install? you have to specify the package name: `sudo apt install ros-noetic-PACKAGE`.

Comment: This command for installing all packages and I tried to specify a package and it's not working either

Comment: If you read section 1.4 on the page you have linked, it says that `sudo apt install ros-noetic-desktop-full` installs everything you need. Given that you have followed the instructions for 1.2 and 1.3

Comment: I run this in the beginning before installing the packages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That’s not the full package name. You should instead be running

```
sudo apt install ros-noetic-desktop-full
```

Comment: I run this in the beginning before installing the packages

Comment: @moayyad what packages are you trying to install then? You don’t specify a valid package name in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you didn't set up your sources.list correctly. When you type `sudo apt install ros-` and then press `[tab]` does it autocomplete to `sudo apt install ros-noetic-`?

If not check steps 1.1 to 1.3 again. [1](http://wiki.ros.org/noetic/Installation/Ubuntu)

If it autocompletes then you can install `sudo apt install ros-noetic-desktop-full`. After this you have all the most common packages like `rviz`, `actionlib` etc. If you need any additional packages then install them with `sudo apt install ros-noetic-<package name>` where `<package name>` has to be replaced with the name of the package you want to install. Like `sudo apt install ros-noetic-moveit`.

Answer (score -1):

Run the Below commands One By One.

***To install ROS ~ Noetic***

1. sudo apt update
2. sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list'
3. sudo apt install curl
4. curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/ros.asc | sudo apt-key add -
5. sudo apt install ros-noetic-desktop-full

**# Below commands for Install  dependencies for the ROS packages.**

6. sudo rosdep init
7. rosdep update

**# To setup Environment for ROS**

8. echo "source /opt/ros/noetic/setup.bash" >> ~/.bashrc
9. source ~/.bashrc